# Full steps of definite integral on mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How to see all the steps of integration in mathematica. here is the integration:

```
Integrate[y^(k/2 + p - 1)*(0.5*x + 1)^(-2*w - k*ls - 2*r)/
E^(y/2), {y, 0, gamma}]
```

Comment: okay, thank you

Comment: See [`Rubi`](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/index.html)